# How do I automatically generate meta tags on node creation using the Nodewords module?

Tags: meta-tags

I want to create meta tags automatically on node creation. I am using the Nodewords module.

Comment: -1 on account of not having read the documentation with the module

Comment: I have already this documentation and this thing is not working unless i go to edit form and set meta tag title for that node. og:title is not generated on node creation

Comment: If you did read the documentation, you should write that (and specify what you read) in your question.  If you are having trouble with a title for organic groups, you should edit your question and add that information as well.  However, if this only affects organic groups, and automatic generation works for other content types, then this is probably a bug/incompatibility between organic groups and nodewords.  In that case, you should file an issue on one of those module's issue queues instead of asking here.  Bug reports are out of scope for this site.

Comment: Also, please ensure you're using 6.x-1.13 or newer, older versions had lots of problems. Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the [Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation included with the module in the README.txt states:

> Configuration
>
> 1. On the access control administration page ("Administer >> User management >> Access control") you need to assign:
>
>    - The "administer meta tags" permission to the roles that are allowed to
>      administer the meta tags (such as setting the default values and/or
>      enabling the possibility to edit them),
>    - The "edit XYZ tag" permission to the roles that are allowed to set and
>      edit meta tags for the content (there is a permission for each of the
>      meta tags currently defined).
>
>    All users will be able to see the assigned meta tags.
> 2. On the settings page ("Administer >> Content management >> Meta tags") you
>    can specify the default settings for the module. To access this page users
>    need the "administer meta tags" permission.
> 3. You should enable meta tags for editing before they are available for use.
>    The same operation should be done for meta tag output. Only allowed Meta
>    tags are available for editing or exposed in the HTML of your site.
> 4. The front page is an important page for each website, therefore you can
>    specifically set the meta tags to use on the front page meta tags settings
>    page ("Administer >> Content management >> Meta tags >> Default and
>    specific meta tags >> Front page"). Users need the "administer meta tags"
>    permission to do this. When there are resources providing meta tags
>    promoted in the front page, you may force the usage of "Front page" meta
>    tags superseding all of them.
>
>    Alternatively, you can opt not to set the meta tags for the front page on
>    this page, but to use the meta tags of the node, term or other page the
>    used to control the front page. To do this, uncheck the "Use front page
>    meta tags" option on the main settings page.
>
>    Note that, in contrast to previous versions of this module, the site
>    mission and/or site slogan are no longer used as DESCRIPTION or ABSTRACT
>    on the front page!
> 5. Each content type should be configured to control whether certain meta tags
>    should be automatically generated, e.g. the "description" tag can be
>    automatically taken from the node teaser.

Comment: I have already this documentation and this thing is not working unless i go to edit form and set meta tag title for that node. og:title is not generated on node creation